# How to call a protected void from a public static list

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a public static list with a return because I use it from an AJAX call to the [WebMethod].

I need to call a protected void from that but I can't call a non static member from a static.

This is my webmethod at the moment it calls PopulateBasedOnOpen which at the moment is another static:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string CustType(string custtype)
{
    string test;
    test = custtype.ToString();
    PopulateBasedOnOpen(custtype);
    return test;
}
```

The problem is that in my PopulateBasedOnOpen I need to set values of textboxes that are defined in the aspx which I can't do within a static:

```
protected static string PopulateBasedOnOpen(string CustType) 
{
    //set values of textboxes cant be done here
    return CustType;
}
```

Comment: you need to share them somehow between WebMethod and page. Or by Session, or by loading them from the same datasource that was used for aspx page.

Comment: I don't understand. The issue is assigning them in the first place, I don't know how I can use a session if I can't call a method to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not** change the server `controls` on server side using web method by `ajax` call. As server control state is maintained in `ViewState` and that is not pass in ajax call. You can return the value from server side and use that value in `javascript / jQuery` and assign it to server generated html control

Comment: I will have multiple values for in cases up to 100 or more fields of varying types, do you think it will be easy?

Comment: I think so, you can send json string and use that on client side. You can look on asp.net ajax, updatepanel if you can not feel comfortable with jQuery/javascript

Comment: Could I do something that forces a postback within the method? If I can do that then I can probably find a way to do it without all the fancy stuff.

Comment: The may help, http://madskristensen.net/post/Do-postbacks-with-parameters-in-JavaScript

Comment: It's got nothing to do with server control state being maintained in viewstate (which it sometimes isn't); its

Comment: The problem is not "server control state is maintained in ViewState and that is not pass in ajax call" (which isn't always true anyway, viewstate may be disabled for a control and it will still post a value on postback). The problem is that WebMethods are static members of the page, so there is no "Page" instance or any of its child controls.

Comment: @sh1rts, there would be reason why they made it static.

Comment: That's just the way it is with WebMethods; they have to be static.

Comment: That does not tell the reason

Answer (score 0):

By concept:

**protected**: is accessible **within** its class and by **derived** class instances.

**static**: can be used with classes, fields, methods, properties, operators, events, and constructors, but it cannot be used with indexers, destructors, or types other than classes. The static modifier on a class means that the class cannot be **instantiated**, and that all of its members are static.

Make sure you match those criteria to be able to call your method properly.Maybe you can change your `protected static string PopulateBasedOnOpen(string CustType)` to `public static string PopulateBasedOnOpen(string CustType)`

Comment: I did that change but it still won't allow me to change textbox parameters.

Comment: Make sure that `PopulateBasedOnOpen` is place in the code behind of where the textboxes are created.

Comment: The textboxes arent created in the code-behind they are defined in the aspx page which I mentioned before.